# Use jackson's JsonView Information in mapper class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson, dto

In a Spring Boot REST Application we are using `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView(CalculateStatus.class)`.

It works as designed but the problem is that the whole DTO gets mapped before, which could take a considerable amount of time.

Is it possible to access the `@JsonView` information (that is given by annotating the REST endpoint) somehow in the corresponding mapper class?
I would expect something like:

```
if (JsonView.currentView() == CalculateStatus.class) {
    dto.setStatus(entity.calculateStatus());
}
```

Or is the only solution to use different DTO classes?